# Dynamic Control Flow in DO loop in SAS data step

Tags: sas

Is the inner loop here (marked with ********) okay as is, or do I need to use something like %eval()? (I don't think I need %eval() because there are no macro variables.)

```
do _i = 1 to 5;
   if sp_id_array{_i} ne . then do;
      do _j = (_i+1) to 5; *********;
         if sp_id_array{_j} ne . then do;
            sp_id = sp_id_array{_i};
            sp_partner_id = sp_id_array{_j};
            output;
         end;
      end;
   end;         
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine; SAS will automatically use the (`_i+1`).  In fact, you can modify the loop control variable itself inside the loop.

```
data _null_;
  do _i = 1 to 5;
    put _i=;
    _i=5;
  end;
run;
```